# How to pass text value between two widgets not existing within same file

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following widgets where each widget exists in their own file.

(There is alot more going on in each file. I have condensed it to keep it minimal to only see what's needed for this query).

I wish to capture values passed into a TextFormField within one widget and print out those values in another widget.

There is no visual state changes going on thus trying not to store these values via Provider which I felt would be silly for this usecase.

Thus the query is on how to pass down the value captured in a TextEditingController for each widget's instance and pass it down to another widget?

To reiterate, the following 3 classes, they exist in their own Dart file.

I was initially sticking with stateless widget for all 3 but from what I read up, advice is to user a stateful widget where TextEditingController is involved.

Thus the MyField widget is stateful.

MyField Widget - This is where the value is expected to get stored to controller based on what's been typed in.

```
class MyField extends StatefulWidget {

  final String title;
  final TextEditingController controller;

  const MyField({this.controller, this.title});

  @override
  _MyFieldState createState() => _MyFieldState();
}

class _MyFieldState extends State<MyField> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: widget.controller,
    );
  }
}
```

MyForm Widget - This takes in 2 instances of above widget, each having its own controller.

This widget helps pass on the text values down to the MyButton widget.

```
class MyForm extends StatelessWidget {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final nameController = TextEditingController();
  final passController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: formKey,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          MyField(
            title: 'name',
            controller: nameController,
          ),
          MyField(
            title: 'pass',
            controller: passController,
          ),
          MyButton(
              name: nameController.text,
              pass: passController.text,
              formKey: formKey)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

MyButton Widget - This widget captures those text values and tries to print out the values and it currently comes out empty.

```
class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {

  final formKey;
  final String name;
  final String pass;

  const MyButton({Key key, this.formKey, this.name, this.pass}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        // I want to be able to retrieve the text via the controllers for the 2 text fields.
        // currently these values are empty which is the issue.
        print('name: $name pass: $pass');
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the value in an object file and get or edit its value from any other file in the project.. for example in file named user.dart :

```
class user {
  static String name;
  static String pass;
}
```

then at any other place import the file and set or get its values as you want:

```
user.name = nameController.text
user.pass = passController.text

print('name: ' + user.name + 'pass: ' + user.pass);
```

if your problem is that you want to show the text before the button is clicked, I think you might make your widget stateful and then you can use change event in the Text field:

```
onChanged: (value) {
setState(() { 
user.name = nameController.text;
});}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try.

- Need to change from 'Stack' to 'Column' in MyForm class.
- getting value from TextFormField using 'formKey'
  (Although I used a formkey, but I hope to control value from outside of 'MyForm' than Getting a value by using 'formkey')

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _buildBody(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return MyForm();
  }
}

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final formKey;
  final String label;

  const MyButton({Key key, this.formKey, this.label}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        // I want to be able to retrieve the text via the controllers for the 2 text fields.
        // currently these values are empty which is the issue.
        print(
            'name: ${formKey.currentWidget.child.children[0].controller.text} ');
        print(
            'pass: ${formKey.currentWidget.child.children[1].controller.text} ');
      },
      child: Text(label),
    );
  }
}

class MyForm extends StatelessWidget {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final nameController = TextEditingController();
  final passController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          MyField(
            title: 'name',
            controller: nameController,
          ),
          MyField(
            title: 'pass',
            controller: passController,
          ),
          MyButton(label: 'Button', formKey: formKey)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyField extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final TextEditingController controller;

  const MyField({this.controller, this.title});

  @override
  _MyFieldState createState() => _MyFieldState();
}

class _MyFieldState extends State<MyField> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: widget.controller,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are not using the user typed texts to update the UI state of `MyButton` widget you don't even need it you can just access the controllers texts in `MyForm` widget.

```
class MyForm extends StatelessWidget {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final nameController = TextEditingController();
  final passController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          MyField(
            title: 'name',
            controller: nameController,
          ),
          MyField(
            title: 'pass',
            controller: passController,
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed() {
               print("${nameController.text}");
               print("${passController.text}");
             }
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But if you want to update `MyButton` widget on the fly while the user is typing a text so `MyForm` widgets needs to be `Statefull` and must rebuild in every user type event.

```
 //NOTE: Assuming `MyForm` is a Statefull widget
  final nameController = TextEditingController();
  final passController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
     // listening the textfield.
     nameController.addListener(_controllerListener);
     passController.addListener(_controllerListener);
     super.initState();
  }

  void _controllerListener(){
     if(mounted)
       setState((){});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: formKey,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          MyField(
            title: 'name',
            controller: nameController,
          ),
          MyField(
            title: 'pass',
            controller: passController,
          ),
          MyButton(
              name: nameController.text,
              pass: passController.text,
              onPressed: () {
                 print("${nameController.text} - ${passController.text}");
              })
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;
  final String pass;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  const MyButton({Key key, this.onPressed, this.name, this.pass}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: this.onPressed,

      // updating UI on type event.
      child: Text('$name and $pass'),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please change  `MyForm` class to below Class...
How It Works ?
your Button Should rebuild after each change on TextFormField so I used a Stream builder and a Stream

```
class MyForm extends StatelessWidget {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final nameController = TextEditingController();
  final passController = TextEditingController();

  StreamController<int> sc = StreamController<int>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: formKey,
      onChanged: () {
        sc.add(1);
      },
      child: Column(
        children: [
          MyField(
            title: 'name',
            controller: nameController,
          ),
          MyField(
            title: 'pass',
            controller: passController,
          ),
          StreamBuilder<int>(
            stream: sc.stream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return MyButton(
                  name: nameController.text,
                  pass: passController.text,
                  formKey: formKey);
            }
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```